# Insert a character at a specific location using sed

Tags: sed

How to insert a dash into a string after 4 characters using sed (e.g., `201107` to `2011-07`)?

Answer (score 21):

```
echo "201107" | sed 's/201107/2011-07/'
```

Should work. But just kidding, here's the more general solution:

```
echo "201107" | sed -r 's/(.{4})/\1-/'
```

This will insert a `-` after every four characters.

Answer (score 8):

For uncertain sed version (at least my GNU sed 4.2.2), you could just do:

`echo "201107" | sed 's/./&-/4'`

`/4` -> replace for the 4th occurrence (of search pattern `.`)

`&`  -> back reference to the whole match

I learned this from another post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259718/sed-insert-character-at-specific-positions

Answer (score 0):

The following will match perform the replacement only on strings of four digits, followed by strings of two digits.

```
$ echo '201107' | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1-\2/'
2011-07
```

Sed regex is a little awkward, because of the lack of `\d`, and the need to escape parenthesis and braces (but not brakets). My solution *ought* to be `'s/(\d{4})(\d{2})/\1-\2/'` if not for these peculiarities.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is diggin up a massive dinosaur, but if you wanted to eliminate the 6 tailing zeros

```
echo '20110715000000' | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{6\}\)/\1-\2-\3/'
```