# Bulk rename files with pattern (add hyphen at positions)

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to rename a directory with files following this pattern `utbetalning_20170209` to `utbetalning_2017-02-09`.

My thought is to solve it in three passes, by adding hyphens at the correct index position. This can be solved with the `sed` command, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845069/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-using-sed) thread:

```
$ echo "utbetalning_20200325.pdf" | sed 's/./&-/16'
utbetalning_2020-0325.pdf
```

or (another suggested in the same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845069/insert-a-character-at-a-specific-location-using-sed) as above):

```
$ echo "utbetalning_20200325.pdf" | sed 's/^\(.\{16\}\)/\1-/' 
utbetalning_2020-0325.pdf
```

But using these patterns with `rename` *doesn't* change any filename

```
rename 's/./&-/16' *
```

Might be a limitation in `rename`. Any other solution?

Comment: `sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\.pdf/\1-\2-\3.pdf/'`. I advise not to use `rename` unless you know which one you have, there is [perl rename](https://www.linux.pl/man/index.php?command=rename) and [util-linux rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) and both are named the same. You seem to aim for the perl one, but most probably on linux you have the util-linux one (or both).

Comment: @KamilCuk, when echoing the sed pattern you proposed worked as well, but not with `rename`. I've confirmed that I'm using `util-linux-rename`. If using `rename` is bad, what should I do?

Comment: 1. Iterate over list of dirs `find` + https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 2. For each dir 3. Create new filename using sed and save it in a variable (for checking). 4. Execute `mv olddir newdir`

Comment: Yeah, that was what I wanted to avoid, a whole script. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

There should be hundreds of "mass rename tools" available on the internet and surely one of them is runnable under Linux as well :)
So, unless you want to do bash sed, try a search engine and be done in a few minutes, would be my advise.

Comment: I've tried Google, and the recommendation I've found is the rename command.

Comment: @Max Yes. I apologize for my answer and regret writing those words. Was not helpful, was it? ;) I am sorry. Thank you for your comment. The downvote is justified.

Comment: Except maybe, since you asked "Any other solution?" my suggestion is not too far fetched. But worded badly indeed.